# Batch file to append text files, keeping tabs instead of spaces

Tags: batch-file

I have a bunch of text files that I want appending to each other, where the format is like this:

```
April 14, 2014
00:01:14    0.0952      >100        0.0794      >100
```

The date is on the 49th line, and I need all lines following, so I'm currently using the following code:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do more +48 %%a >>##Appended.txt
```

This works, however in the original text files there are tabs between the numbers, and when I use this command these are replaces by spaces. When I paste the appended file into excel it doesn't automatically split the numbers into correct cells, as it did in the original files.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `more`- it will convert tabs to spaces

This will get only line 49 of every `txt`file (if there is one)

```
@echo off
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do call :getline %%f
exit /b

:getline
for /f "tokens=* skip=48 eol=" %%i in (%1) do ( 
 echo %%i>>##Appended.txt
 goto :eof
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: I thought it was to do with the `more` command. The text files contain data (of varying length) below the 49th line, which is what I am appending to each other.

Comment: Ah - I thought, you need ONLY the 49th line. Just remove the first `goto :eof` to get line 49 and all following.

Comment: Stephan, I should have been more clear. But thanks, this works perfectly. Could you briefly explain how this is differing. I assume the second loop is copying line by line, rather than more which was working character by character (?).

Comment: exactly. `more` is intended to show text and probably wasn't ever adapted to "modern techniques" (in the (very) old days, you could not relay, that every terminal had full support of "ControlChars" like `tab`)